# OpenVPN easy-rsa: Common Name set at vars

Tags: openvpn

I got the latest version (3.0.1) of the `easy-rsa` tool from [Github](https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa/releases) in order to generate some certificates for a small VPN. After looking into the documentation I manage to write a `vars` file that include answers to most questions made by the tool including setting the Common Name:

```
set_var EASYRSA_REQ_CN          "vpn.machine.dev"
```

Every other option os correctly loaded / takes the value I set on `vars` by the `easy-rsa` tool however `EASYRSA_REQ_CN` seems to be ignored. Here is an example:

```
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) [IT]:
Common Name (eg: your user, host, or server name) [Easy-RSA CA]:
Email Address [it@machine.dev]:
```

**Why isn't Common Name using the value I set and is defaulting to `[Easy-RSA CA]`? What did I miss?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I just had a quick look at `easy-rsa` source code I found this:

```
# Default CN only when not in global EASYRSA_BATCH mode:
    [ $EASYRSA_BATCH ] && opts="$opts -batch" || export EASYRSA_REQ_CN="Easy-RSA CA"
```

Apparently it will just ignore `EASYRSA_REQ_CN` when not running in batch mode (`EASYRSA_BATCH`). This must be some *by-design* decision that goes out of my understanding of the tool.

For anyone facing the same issue, adding the following to your `vars` will fix this:

```
set_var EASYRSA_BATCH       "yes"
```

**WARNING**: when running in batch mode the tool won't ask for ANY user input and might destroy previous information / generate errors. Test your config before using this mode.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to generate a certificate request. I'm using EasyRSA 3.0.6 this way:

```
EASYRSA_REQ_CN=vpn.machine.dev ./easyrsa --batch gen-req vpn.machine.dev nopass
```